# Выделение памяти при компиляции Java

Tags: java, javac

Не могу разобраться с компиляцией javac-ом. При попытке (даже с параметрами типа Xms1024m/Xmx1024M) компиляции .java-файла выдает ошибку `Invalid maximum heap size`.
Хотелось бы знать, где можно задать выделение памяти для java (32bit, если не ошибаюсь). Панель управления пробовал, не помогает. Странно то, что уже выделено (ну, так в cmd пишет) 4096m (на ноутбуке всего 8Гб ОЗУ).

Comment: а свободно сколько в момент выделения ?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, ~4 гигабайта

Comment: приложите логи к телу вопроса

Comment: javac вашкласс.java -J-Xmx4g, вроде для 32бита 4гига это предел мечтаний

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с вопросом сам. 
В общем, сделал через переменную окружения _JAVA_OPTIONS, выставив параметр -Xmx1G.